# Delay before touchscreen becomes operational

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen

I have an HP Spectre with a touch screen. It was working alright a few days ago, but recently it has started giving off a delay of up to one minute before I am able to use the touchscreen properly. It does respond kind of feebly, but I am not able to use it properly immediately after boot. It works fine after the system is put to sleep and wakes up. Automatic updates are turned on and I have Windows 10 home edition running on the system. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The article
[How to Fix Your Touchscreen in Windows 10](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-touchscreen-windows-10/)
nicely details the actions that you may take with screenshots.
Here is the synopsis :

1. Run Control Panel > Troubleshooting > Hardware and Devices, and let it do its work.
   Listed problems will need to be addressed.
2. Calibrate the touchscreen.
3. Disable and re-enable the touchscreen in Device Manager.
4. Update the driver, downloading it from the manufacturer's website.